# Большая [ошибка] в названии метки

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Предлагаю удалить метку [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0). Не вижу в ней смысла, во многих вопросах и так понятно, что где-то ошибка, иначе бы пользователь не задавал вопрос. Специалистов по ошибкам тоже быть не может, а это признак мета-метки.

[errors](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errors) и [error](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) нашел, в ту же кучу.

Comment: Да, толку от нее немного (впрочем, как и от большей части других меток). А вот вопросы, не связанные непосредственно с ошибками к счастью (пока еще) встречаются. (в рамках флуда: imho специалисты по ошибкам вполне возможны, также как и специалисты по решению проблем (обычно за немалые деньги)).

Comment: @avp поправил немного.

Comment: Либо тогда ещё добавить метки _проблема_ (такая, оказывается, есть) и _трагедия_, чтобы можно было охарактеризовать любой вопрос.

Comment: @Regent ещё [tag:бида]

Comment: трагедия? круто, вот это я понимаю) у кого-то чувство юмора в порядке.

Comment: @VladD, как вариант *teh-drama*

Comment: предлагаю (для поддержания баланса) метку *комедия*.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну, кому-то с dirty.ru или лепры. (Сотру, офтопик всё же.)

Comment: @Discord вот я тоже пытался вставить [ошибку] в заголовок, но не смог, система не дает. Теперь знаю, как )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот и подчистили метку. Всех поздравляю.

Comment: Ура, товарищи!​

Answer (score 5):

Написал следующий текст в описание метки:

---

> НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ. Лучше напишите подробно, в чем ошибка. Обязательно добавьте к вопросу полученное вами сообщение об ошибке.  Если ошибка вызвана кодом - приложите код.
>
> Подробнее читайте здесь: [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

---

UPD: не помогло. [NullPointerException после jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(...)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432020/181472)!

Comment: где? что? куда смотреть?

Comment: @Nofate там был вопрос "Вылетает ошибка" с меткой [ошибка] - но метку редакторы уже убрали. Я имел в виду что даже явное указание не помешало человеку использовать метку. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/432020/revisions

Comment: А, это. Тут медицина бессильна. Описание нужно в большей степени, чтобы напоминать активным пользователям.

Answer (score 4):

Соглашусь, метка бесполезная. Но удалить ее возможности нет.  А вычищать вручную - на главной всплывет много старья и часть участников взвоет, как это бывает в таких случаях.

Предлагаю в описание метки пока написать как обычно *"НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ. Это мета-метка, бла бла бла"* и вычищать небольшими порциями.

Comment: Что-то слышал о том, что у модераторов есть инструменты для массового редактирования, после которого посты не всплывают.

Comment: Только для слияния/переименования меток

Comment: Нет никакого функционала, чтобы можно было заблокировать метку для использования, но не удалять ее (возможно, временно)?

Comment: @soon, увы, нет

Comment: Насколько это может быть полезно? Как часто бывают ситуации, когда не получается удалить метку прямо сейчас, но она явно не несет никакой пользы? На SO куча меток, в которых также написано "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Comment: @soon у нас-то вообще такие количества, что можно вручную перебрать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, но такая проблема не только у нас.

Comment: @soon возникла идея: все неугодные метки синонимизировать к метке [неправильная-метка]. Или [удали-эту-метку].

Comment: @Nofate как вам идея синонимизировать все неудачные метки к [удалите-эту-метку]?

Comment: Мне кажется, это будет дизориентировать пользователя. С другой стороны, это не потребует изменений в движке. Надо поискать, скорее всего подобный вопрос уже возникал на большом SO

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это может кого-то смутить, пользователь решит, что речь об удалении вопроса, начнет тревоги жать... Хотя решение удобное.

Comment: @Nofate а если [не-используйте-эту-метку]? И в выдержке написать, что на нее автозаменяются все неподходящие. Про удаление речь не идет, авось не напугаются.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, так определенно лучше. Каждый, кто будет ее видеть, (вероятно) будет мотивирован убрать ее из вопроса.