# Большая [ошибка] в синонимах

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Не так давно обсуждалась [Большая [ошибка] в названии метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/549/181472). Раз уж удалять ее <s>опасно</s> нежелательно, хотелось бы добавить синонимы:

- [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0) < [error](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error)
- [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0) < [errors](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errors)

Сам не могу предложить синонимы, не эксперт по ошибкам. =)